# Equations not centered using align

Tags: align

I use the following latex code to using `align` environment but the formula does not appear centered.

```
\begin{align}
    \text{$SM$}_7 \rightarrow \text{$SM$}_1 :  \{K_{NG},HMAC_{K_{1}}\}_{\{encr\}K_{1}},
\end{align}
```

But when writing the same code in IEEE journal latex file, the formula was centered. 
Can any one help me to make text within `align` to be centered ??

[image]

Comment: Usually it will be centered, so can you make a complete example (a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)) that demonstrates the problem? And unrelated, but why write `\text{$SM$}` instead of just `SM`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image I would guess you have the `fleqn` option to set math flush left which is why it is not centred but `align` should never be used for one-lien equations

```
\begin{align}
    \text{$SM$}_7 \rightarrow \text{$SM$}_1 :  \{K_{NG},HMAC_{K_{1}}\}_{\{encr\}K_{1}},
\end{align}
```

should be

```
\begin{equation}
    SM_7 \rightarrow SM_1 :  \{K_{NG},HMAC_{K_{1}}\}_{\{encr\}K_{1}},
\end{equation}
```

or perhaps

```
\begin{equation}
    \mathit{SM}_7 \rightarrow \mathit{SM}_1 :  \{K_{NG},HMAC_{K_{1}}\}_{\{encr\}K_{1}},
\end{equation}
```

if *SM* is a single identifier here not a combination of *S* and *M*